# Can Changelings talk when they aren't in humanoid form?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, changeling

Odo has certainly shown the ability to sense activity around him when he is morphed into other shapes. He shows the ability to hear a conversation between Worf, Quark, and a smuggler while taking the form of a case in "Hippocratic Oath."

Since cases don't have ears and yet Odo heard the conversation just as well, can it be concluded that Changelings (Odo in particular) can speak even when taking forms of inanimate or mouthless objects?

Answer (score 9):

Well, "hearing" sounds is really just receiving the vibrations of sound waves in organs that are sensitive to such, and interpreting them in our brains.  Given that changelings are amorphous pools of goo in "natural" form, perhaps they can detect and interpret those vibrations anywhere along their surface.  That would explain how Odo could "hear" in a shape without ears.

Speaking, however, would require some means of *generating sound waves* with appropriate frequency and modulation.  So no, I don't think he could speak without having a mouth and vocal chords (or something equally capable of making noise.)  I'm not aware of any canon that would prevent him from simply creating the requisite organs somewhere on his body if he wanted to speak while in the form of something that doesn't normally have a mouth, though.

I recall Odo expressing a certain amount of pride in accurately taking the shapes of things around him and "becoming" those things - but that would only stop him for as long as he wanted it to.

Comment: Generating sounds doesn't require special organs, it just requires highly controlled vibration. If Odo can do that with a part in contact with air, then he's in business. I suppose the question is - can he.

Comment: @MishaRosnach My guess would be that Odo may or may not be able to, since he's had trouble with shapeshifting before, but other Changelings probably could.

Comment: @MishaRosnach As a concrete example: That's exactly how electronic speakers work. An electromagnet is used to induce controlled vibrations in a surface for the purpose of generating compression waves (sound).

Answer (score 5):

It seems very possible that Changelings could emit sounds while in certain shapes.

We know a few things:

Odo isn't a naturally great shapeshifter. Other changelings (Laas in particular) point this out to him, such as the fact he didn't realize it was possible to shapeshift into fire or fog. Though he does learn some tricks from his time with Laas. It stands to reason that Odo is not an example of the limits of shapeshifting. That said, we can't assume the others can do anything we don't see on screen.

Odo can hear while shapeshifted. All hearing requires is the ability to experience and interpret vibrations. Odo may be able to use his whole form as a microphone, or perhaps transform a particular piece of himself into a microphone/ear. His ability to interpret the captured vibrations is unknown, but we have evidence it is possible.

Odo can create objects that he then appears to interact with. On one occasion he shapeshifts into himself as well as a dinner, so that he can "mime" the act of eating along for the social benefits, without having to consume actual matter.

It is mentioned that Odo actually shapeshifts his commbadge into existence, and it functions just like the starfleet issued ones. This shows that he is capable of creating a speaker.

In conclusion it seems likely (though not proven) that Odo could "speak" or at least emit sounds while shapeshifted. He has multiple ways he could do this using the abilities demonstrated on screen. Either by shapeshifting into a traditional electronic speaker, or by directly manipulating his form to vibrate and produce sound.

[Odo entry on Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Odo)